# Panamax Surge Protector says outlet is faulty; Radioshack tester says its AOK

Tags: receptacle

I have a surge protector / line conditioner for my AV equipment. I just moved it to a new receptacle and the unit is indicating there's a problem (see attached image).

However, when I test with my ancient outlet tester, it comes up "Correct" and everything seems peachy. I'd love to get a sense of what's amiss before I invest in a visit from an electrician. Any ideas? [image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is this outlet tester one with three lamps, two of which should be lit? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Yes. The tester has three LEDs and there were two green LEDs lit for this receptacle. The Panamax surge protector has a line fault indicator, but the manual doesn't really go into details about what's it's detecting.

Comment: It's hard to tell from here, but my guess is that your surge protector is faulty. But again: we can't know for sure remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the cheap little 3 prong outlet testers with thee LEDs cannot detect a "bootleg ground", ie where the ground and neutral are swapped or connected together. The surge protector may be able to tell the difference because for that device, this is a more critical necessity, which would explain the discrepancy.